# Find $\int^{\pi/2}_{{0}} \operatorname{arccot}(1-x+x^2)\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find integral of $$\int\limits^{\frac{{\pi}}{2}}_{{0}} \operatorname{arccot}\left(1-x+x^2\right)\,dx $$

More specifically,

> Show that $$\displaystyle\int\limits^{\frac{{\pi}}{2}}_{{0}} \operatorname{arccot}\left(1-x+x^2\right)\,dx    =  \frac{\pi}{2}- \log(2)$$

I started out with integration by parts since I could not make a efficient substitution. I now have $-x\operatorname{arccot}\left(x^2+x-1\right)-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\left(2x+1\right)x}{\left(x^2+x-1\right)^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$, which just seems more complex. Any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Working:[image]

Comment: for the second component of your last step, you can expand the integral by partial fraction decomposition. You will now find $\int\bigg(-\dfrac{2x^2}{(x^2+x-1)^2+1} - \dfrac{x}{(x^2+x-1)+1} \bigg) \textrm{d}x$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed, since factoring the denominator looks difficult.

Comment: The solution looks also difficult.

Comment: Are you sure you typed it right? Why would anyone ever combine $\arctan $ with $\frac{\pi}{2}$ I bet the upper bound is $1$.

Comment: Your integration result must be $$x arccot(1-x-x^2)-\int\frac{x(2x+1)}{(1-x-x^2)^2+1}dx$$

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle\int\limits^{\frac{{\pi}}{2}}_{{0}} \operatorname{arccot}\left(1-x-x^2\right)\,dx $$   \ne  \frac{\pi}{2}- \log(2)$. This can be verified by wolfram alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+arccot(1-x-x%5E2)+from+0+to+pi%2F2

Comment: Hi guys, I just realized I made a mistake in the signs in the problem and my working. I shall make the appropriate changes. Sorry.

Comment: If the upper limit is 1 rather than $\pi/2$ then the result is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1-x+x^2}\right)=\arctan(1-x)+\arctan x$$
But we don't need to evaluate two integrals since using the substitution $1-x=x$ there is
$$\int_0^1 \arctan(1-x)dx=\int_0^1\arctan xdx$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^1 \text{arccot}(1-x+x^2)dx=2\int_0^1 \arctan xdx$$
$$=2x\arctan x|_0^1 -\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln 2$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$$\begin{align}\operatorname{arccot}\left(1-x+x^2\right)&=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1-x(1-x)}\right)\\&=\arctan\left(\frac{1-x+x}{1-x(1+x)}\right)\\&=\arctan(1-x)+\arctan(x)\end{align}$$